# How to make my web page display in full in any browser window of any size

Tags: css, cross-browser, webbrowser-control

I have made a webpage and this is the code to the main div.

```
#Div {
    margin-left: 0px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: -1px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #030;
    width: 660px;
    margin-left:-330px;
    left:50%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 440px;
}
```

Is there a css technique i can use to make sure the page occupies the whole page no matter the size of the computer screen the browser is on.

Comment: Oh, if that's your question, then simply write `html, body { padding: 0; margin 0; } ` at the top of your css

Comment: This CSS is just wrong. Please learn about CSS 'position', 'display' and 'float' and you will know why I'm telling you this. The combination of this CSS properties will give you nothing. If you want the 'div' in all the window just do 'body { padding: 0; margin 0; }' and 'div { width:100% }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you setting `margin-left` twice? Why are you floating (and displaying inline) a div that you want to take up the whole screen? Setting a negative left margin will move your whole div to the left, and therefore cause it to not reach all the way to the right even when the `width: 100%`.

Take away all margins. Do `width:100%`. change `display:inline` to `display:block`. Take away the float. If you *have* to set this to `position:absolute`, then be sure to specify: **top: 0px; left: 0px**

Answer (score 1):

min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;

and use a CSS Reset - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: I'm not sure that setting the height with 100% works.  At least it usually doesn't for me...?

Comment: did you use the css reset? Different browsers show borders, padding and margins differently, you can set these to 0 with css resets

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447456/what-the-typical-viewport-size-on-a-1024x768-screen

Answer (score 1):

You want to center your webpage, without beeing cut at the left on small screens?

Use following:

```
#outer{
  text-align: center;
}
#inner{
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 660px;
  text-align: left;
}

<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can take some inspiration from a CSS framework and strip out the bits that you need? http://cssgrid.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
  #container {
    background: blue;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    2border: 1px solid red;
  }



<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Answer can *always* be improved by adding some text. Code-only question and answers are discouraged. Just a heads up.