# Why does Mobile IE6 use a layout viewport of 974px?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-mobile, internet-explorer-6, viewport, windows-mobile-6.5

Why does Internet Explorer Mobile 6 use [a layout viewport of 974px](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html)?

974 seems like a suspiciously precise number.

Comment: 974 or 947?  Also, which *specific* version of IE are we talking about here?  Keep in mind that different versions of the IE rendering engine shipped with different versions of Windows Mobile / CE / Phone.

Comment: Question updated, thanks. I do not know the answer to your question. I am repeating information gleaned from http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html. The article was written in 2010.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that.  According to the [resulting table](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html), the IE version in question is "Internet Explorer Mobile 6", released as part of Windows Mobile 6.5.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Mobile#Internet_Explorer_Mobile_6) says that MS says it uses *the same layout engine as desktop IE6*, which might be interesting or important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is chosen for 1024x768 monitors, which were the de facto standard for a long time. 1024 - 974 = 50, which allowed for 25px margins on each side.

> For 1024×768 screen resolution, the approximate visible area is 974×650.

Many grid systems use that width, such as the following:

- [Widths table: Device Pixels](http://yui.github.io/yui2/docs/yui_2.9.0_full/examples/grids/grids-doc4.html)
- [Ultimate Guide to Social Media Image Sizes
  (pdf)](https://www.wku.edu/delo/marketing/documents/social-media-image-sizes.pdf)
- [Illustrator Grid](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/widths.html)
- [HTML5 Boilerplate Mobile](http://www.markskowrondesign.com/blog/convert-your-site-to-be-mobile-friendly-using-css-media-queries/)
- [An Introduction to Grid Systems](http://theme.fm/2011/06/an-introduction-to-grid-systems-353/)
- [Optimal width for 1024px resolution](http://www.cameronmoll.com/archives/001220.html)
- [What the typical viewport size on a 1024x768 screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447456/1113772)